# nginx configuration for multiple upstream servers in ansible

Tags: nginx, ansible

I have an ansible playbook which installs a set of HTTP servers. As load balancer / reverse proxy I'm installing an nginx server in a docker container, too.

Depending on the environment I have a different count of upstream HTTP servers, declared as hosts in the `hosts.yml` in the different inventories:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
      ...
    server2:
      ...
    ...
  vars:
    ...

  children:
    upstream-server:
      hosts:
        server1:
          upstream_id: "1"
        server2:
          upstream_id: "2"
        ...
    nginx:
      hosts:
        server1:
          ...
      vars:
        upstream_hosts: server upstream1:8080; server upstream2:8080; ...
```

As I need to declare each of the upstream servers in the `nginx.conf`, I'm currently using a variable `upstream_hosts` which contains the definition of all upstream servers. In my playbook I replace a placeholder in the `nginx.conf` with that variable during creation of the Dockerfile.

I know that I could create the variable `upstream_hosts` with `set_facts` and `with_items: "{{ groups['upstream-server'] }}"`. But I'm wondering if there isn't something easier, where I maybe don't need to change the nginx.conf at all?